flutter_blue_plus example can't connect to esp32
I am trying to connect to esp32 using BLE to communicate with my flutter app.
I clone the flutter_blue_plus example here:
https://github.com/boskokg/flutter_blue_plus/tree/master/example
I run the example folder with android studio simulator(Pixel 4 XL API 30 Android 11.0).
And my esp32 code is also from example library:
#include <BLEDevice.h>
#include <BLEServer.h>
#include <BLEUtils.h>
#include <BLE2902.h>

BLEServer* pServer = NULL;
BLECharacteristic* pCharacteristic = NULL;
bool deviceConnected = false;
bool oldDeviceConnected = false;
uint32_t value = 0;

// See the following for generating UUIDs:
// https://www.uuidgenerator.net/

#define SERVICE_UUID        "4fafc201-1fb5-459e-8fcc-c5c9c331914b"
#define CHARACTERISTIC_UUID "beb5483e-36e1-4688-b7f5-ea07361b26a8"


class MyServerCallbacks: public BLEServerCallbacks {
    void onConnect(BLEServer* pServer) {
      deviceConnected = true;
      BLEDevice::startAdvertising();
    };

    void onDisconnect(BLEServer* pServer) {
      deviceConnected = false;
    }
};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Create the BLE Device
  BLEDevice::init("ESP32 makeNTU");

  // Create the BLE Server
  pServer = BLEDevice::createServer();
  pServer->setCallbacks(new MyServerCallbacks());

  // Create the BLE Service
  BLEService *pService = pServer->createService(SERVICE_UUID);

  // Create a BLE Characteristic
  pCharacteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(
                      CHARACTERISTIC_UUID,
                      BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ   |
                      BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE  |
                      BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_NOTIFY |
                      BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_INDICATE
                    );

  // https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.descriptor.gatt.client_characteristic_configuration.xml
  // Create a BLE Descriptor
  pCharacteristic->addDescriptor(new BLE2902());

  // Start the service
  pService->start();

  // Start advertising
  BLEAdvertising *pAdvertising = BLEDevice::getAdvertising();
  pAdvertising->addServiceUUID(SERVICE_UUID);
  pAdvertising->setScanResponse(false);
  pAdvertising->setMinPreferred(0x0);  // set value to 0x00 to not advertise this parameter
  BLEDevice::startAdvertising();
  Serial.println("Waiting a client connection to notify...");
}

void loop() {
    // notify changed value
    if (deviceConnected) {
        pCharacteristic->setValue((uint8_t*)&value, 4);
        pCharacteristic->notify();
        value++;
        delay(500); // bluetooth stack will go into congestion, if too many packets are sent, in 6 hours test i was able to go as low as 3ms
    }
    // disconnecting
    if (!deviceConnected && oldDeviceConnected) {
        delay(500); // give the bluetooth stack the chance to get things ready
        pServer->startAdvertising(); // restart advertising
        Serial.println("start advertising");
        oldDeviceConnected = deviceConnected;
    }
    // connecting
    if (deviceConnected && !oldDeviceConnected) {
        // do stuff here on connecting
        oldDeviceConnected = deviceConnected;
    }
}

When I run my app, it looks like this:

It seems that it can successfully scan some device, but not my esp32.
Also, everytime I scan, the app can only show 2 devices everytime.
I have changed the android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml according to the documentation:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue_plus
I can find my esp32 using nRF Connect app in my iphone.
So why can't my app find my esp32? What should I have to change to make it work? Thanks!

You should try running it on a physical device, not an emulator. What you're scanning is possibly related to the Bluetooth simulation feature of the emulator.
